# How does Java Synchronized compare locked objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I want to lock an object over multiple API requests such that only one request per user can enter a block of code.

Does `synchronized(obj)` lock based on the object's reference or its `hashCode()` function?

I.e. could I do:

```
synchronized("asdf") {
    doSomethingNifty();
}
```

Here "asdf" has a unique hash but no unique reference.

Comment: It synchronizes on the object.

Comment: `"asdf"` does in fact have a unique reference: it's a string literal, and all string literals reference the same `String` instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does synchronized(obj) lock based on the object's memory location or its toHash() function?

Neither.  It is locking on the monitor associated with the the object.  In terms of the JVM we don't talk about an object's memory address because it is relocatable and it's not the hash code (even in terms of `Object.hashcode()`) because that is not unique.

In terms of what you *should* be locking on, it should be the same `final` object.  Something like:

```
private final Object lockObject = new Object();
...
synchronized (lockObject) {
   // do stuff that needed to be protected
}
```

You want it to be `final` so that multiple threads can be guaranteed to be locking on the same object reference that is not changing.  `private` is good so outside classes can't screw up the locking inside of a class.

> Here "asdf" has a unique hash but no unique memory address.

`"asdf"` does *not* have a unique hash since other strings might have the same hash and it actually *may* have a unique "memory address" across all usage of "asdf" in your application if the compiler stores it in the [Java string pool](https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool).  That means that some completely different class might also have the same bad pattern code block and would affect the synchronization of your class because it would be locking on the same `String` object instance.  That's why a `private` lock object is so important.

While we are on the subject, you must also never synchronize on a mutable value like a non-final object like `Boolean` or `Integer`.  The following pattern is used often and is very wrong:

```
Boolean value = false;
...
// really bad idea
synchronized (value) {
   if (value) {
      value = false;
   } else {
      value = true;
   }
}
```

This is *very wrong* because the `value` reference is changing.  So one thread might lock on it and then change it's reference value so another thread would lock on another object and both threads would be within the `synchronized` at the same time.  It is even worse because with a `Boolean` there are only 2 values of `true` and `false` which are constants so multiple classes would then be locking on the same references.

Answer (score 2):

You're synchronizing over an object, the memory address problem is purely an implementation one and doesn't concern you. As long as it's the same object (meaning the exact same instance), the synchronization is done.

If you use a different instance, the synchronization won't work. What you can do is define a public static constant as the lock :

```
public final static Object LOCK = new Object();
```

and use it

```
synchronized(SomeClass.LOCK) {
```

Comment: Why `String` instead of `Object`?

Comment: Synchronizing on string literal values is bad practice, and can cause bugs. The string literal "asdf" appears in the bytecode as a string constant, and this is 'interned' at class load time. If two classes do this with the same string, then both fields reference the same interned string. This means that you have a single lock object, when you thought you had two. Hence, you may see incorrect behaviour, or even deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

The lock is on the instance of object itself, which you can think of as the memory location if you want to think about it like that.  So what you're suggesting won't work.

Instead, it sounds like you just need to have a single object corresponding to the block of code that you want to protect.  So somewhere in the setup process for your program you need something like

```
static Object lockObject = new Object();
```

and then you can do

```
synchronized(lockObject) {
    doSomethingNifty();
}
```

However, if doSomethingNifty() relates to a particular object, then it would make a lot of sense to use that object instead of lockObject.  Also make sure that doSomethingNifty() is fast to execute, otherwise there'll be a lot of users left waiting.

Comment: `lockObject` should be `final` more than `static`.

Comment: @Gray yeah sure :-), but I pretty much always find that I need there to be just one `lockObject` for all instances of whatever class the `lockObject` lives in.  If so, then `static` is really required.  I agree that `final` is good, very accurate etc, but it's just protecting against accidental change of lockObject which is an unlikely programming error if it's a single purpose object which is just used for synchronization purposes.

Comment: Understood.  FYI: `final` also has a number of other benefits in a multithreaded program around object initialization.